# Manipulations with dates in crontab format in java

Tags: java, date, cron

I need to process a set of crontab configs and shift dates using some offsets, for example, I have

```
29  23  *   *   1-4
```

and offset is +1 hour, so I need

```
29  00  *   *   2-5
```

Are there any java libraries that provides convinient manipulations on days of week - I don't want to specify year, month etc for them.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [Quartz Scheduler framework](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) has support for parsing this format.

If you need a framework to manipulate time entities, look at [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). `LocalDate`, `Period` and `Interval` should help to convert the format above into real dates.

This also looks interesting: https://github.com/anderswisch/cron-expression

Comment: I don't have an issue parsing cron, what I want to do is something like  d = Day('Monday', 20, 10). d.add(1 hour). print d.day; print d.hour; but I don't see how time primitives that you mentioned allow me to do it.

Comment: I don't know any framework which can modify cron expressions. So you will have to parse it and then examine the parse tree / result.